# What IP's to whitelist for Azure Analysis Services European regions?

Tags: azure, azure-analysis-services

In order to connect to Azure Analysis Services from on-prem servers I need to request changes in the on-prem firewall which includes knowing destination IP's.

My Azure Analysis Services instances are located in the north and west europe region:

- westeurope.asazure.windows.net
- norheurope.asazure.windows.net

I am unable to find which IP's are behind above two domain names. Does somebody know which IP addresses are behind these? For Azure SQL there is a proxy gateway you can use for this. Maybe there is something similar for Azure Analysis Services?

Answer (score 0):

You can download Azure IP Ranges here:

- [Azure IP Ranges and Service Tags – Public Cloud](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519)

You may want to investigate on-premises data gateway if you don't want to whitelist the whole datacenters:

- [Install and configure an on-premises data gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-gateway-install)

If you need the other way around you can configure a firewall for your Azure Analysis Services server:

- [Quickstart: Configure server firewall - Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-qs-firewall)

Comment: Don't want to whitelist them all. An on-premises data gateway is required when one or more Azure Analysis Services servers in the same region connect to on-premises data sources. I need to other way around. On-prem to azure.